# Why doesn't my laptop screen brightness go down when unplugged after 11.04 to 11.10 upgrade?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, laptop, screen, brightness

As stated above, after the upgrade to 11.10 my laptop no longer dims the screen when I go on battery power. Why?

Comment: I've made your question a question :). Leave rants on the forums please :).

Answer (score 1):

From system settings, go to Screen, and enable the option to dim to save power:

[image: I like pie.]

Comment: The setting was on by default, it just doesn't do what it should.
It just dims the screen when I'm not doing anything.

Comment: Well for me it dims my screen when I unplug the power cord, but only if I'm not doing anything. It's kind complicated - but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Go to the below Screen setting while on Ac & uncheck  the "Dim screen...' box

Now unplug power from the laptop & move the slider back & forth a bit, then set it to the brightness you wish for when on battery.

Plug power back in, hopefully it should return to full brightness, unplug & again hopefully the screen should dim.

If all that works you can check the 'Dim ..' box or just leave unchecked

The whole system doesn't quite make sense, I'm thinking the check box relates to Ac only

Comment: Didn't work. The new ubuntu just completely ignores the fact that it's connected or not. At least on my Asus 1001HA.

Comment: Hi, this worked for me. The slider doesn't update when you plug or unplug the cable. When plugged in, move the slider near the top, as you find comfortable, close the setting. Unplug, go back to the brightness settings, move the slider to dark side. Close the panel. Now the screen goes dark when unplugged and bright when plugged in.